# How to check if the Skype Client is sign in or sign out inside my Android Application programmatically?

Tags: android, skype

I want to know if there any method to check if my Skype client is sign in or sign out inside my Andriod Application. Actually I'm using  [Skype Uri](https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference) to perform my App functionality.

Anyone can help me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect, but what I'm doing is to check the number of Skype contacts in the Android Contacts DB. With later version of Skype (I'm using 4.7.0.45315) when you log out it clears that user's Skype contacts.

```
final String skypeTestCallID = "echo123";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

Cursor skypeContactsCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    null, "mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/com.skype.android.videocall.action' "
        + "and data_sync1 != '" + skypeTestCallID + "'", null, null);

boolean isLoggedInToSkype = skypeContactsCursor.getCount() == 0;
<etc>
```

The obvious flaw is that you can't differentiate between being 'not logged in' and 'logged in, with no contacts in your account', but for most scenarios it's a close enough approximation.

If anyone has a better approach I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you explain how to use skypeContactsCursor after query done. how to check if it's contain "echo123", maybe we can recommend this solution.@Damian

Comment: @Hema - just call Cursor.getCount() to see how many Skype contacts have been returned from the query. If none, then assume not logged in.
Can you explain what you mean by 'how to check if it's contain "echo123"'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've just run your code it's working good but it require to sync skype contacts with your native contacts otherwise Cursor.getCount() always return 0 even if you are logged in. I used Skybe version (4.7.0.43514). So it's not recommended approach! @Damian